# How to add a property to ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, binding

Hi All I this question

I've this resources Dictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="IconsBrush" x:Name="IconBrush" Color="#FF090909"/>
<Canvas x:Key="NoState" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="204.789368" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="204.8125" x:Shared="false">
    <Path x:Name="NoStateX" Data="F1M121.621,0L72.125,49.496 22.625,0 0,22.625 49.496,72.125 0,121.621 22.625,144.25 72.125,94.75 121.621,144.25 144.25,121.621 94.75,72.125 144.25,22.625z" 
              Height="144.25" Canvas.Left="30.281" Canvas.Top="29.484" Width="144.25"/>
        <Path x:Name="NoStateCircle" Data="M199.726,102.402C199.726,156.152 156.152,199.727 102.402,199.727 48.648,199.727 5.074,156.152 5.074,102.402 5.074,48.649 48.648,5.074 102.402,5.074 156.152,5.074 199.726,48.649 199.726,102.402z" 
              Stroke="#FF44A8E4" StrokeThickness="10.148" StrokeLineJoin="Round" 
              Height="204.801" Canvas.Left="0.004" Canvas.Top="-0.793" Width="204.8"/>
```

The question is :
Is possible to pass a property instead of value , so when merge the dictionary I can pass the value from this property like this vay:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="IconsBrush" x:Name="IconBrush" Color="{Binding MyPropertyColor}"/>
```

and from another assembly where I'll merge this Dictionary I pass the value like this mode:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyAssemblyName;component/Themes/MYResourcesDictionary.xaml" />       
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <MyResourcesDictionary.MyPropertyColor="Color.Black"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>               
</UserControl.Resources>
```